# Multiprocessing: use only the physical cores?

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function `foo` which consumes a lot of memory and which I would like to run several instances of in parallel.

Suppose I have a CPU with 4 physical cores, each with two logical cores.

My system has enough memory to accommodate 4 instances of `foo` in parallel but not 8. Moreover, since 4 of these 8 cores are logical ones anyway, I also do not expect using all 8 cores will provide much gains above and beyond using the 4 physical ones only.

So I want to run `foo` on the 4 physical cores *only*. In other words, I would like to ensure that doing `multiprocessing.Pool(4)` (4 being the maximum number of concurrent run of the function I can accommodate on this machine due to memory limitations) dispatches the job to the four physical cores (and not, for example, to a combo of two physical cores and their two logical offsprings).

How to do that in python?

## Edit:

I earlier used a code example from `multiprocessing` but I am library agnostic ,so to avoid confusion, I removed that.

Comment: @GáborErdős but does that pool all the *physical* cores or just the first four cores?

Comment: @GáborErdős: are you sure? `import psutils` `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)`  seems to know the difference.

Comment: @Yugi: no I do not think it is a duplicate, though my question may have been wrongly formulated (in that there was an undue emphasize on the 'all' part).

Comment: Isn't OS supposed to take care of distributing processes to the core optimally? If you let OS do it, it should be better, because there may be another unrelated process spending 100% of one of the cores and the OS will do the right thing in that situation.

Comment: @zvone: interesting: so if I  call `multiprocessing.Pool(4)` and no other process runs, then only the physical cores will be called on to do the computations?

Comment: I don't really know, but I guess the OS should be smart enough to do that if that is optimal.

Comment: @zvone: 'you can't get an is from an ought'. In other languages (such as [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/detectCores.html)) the multiprocessing has a specific option to  only pool the physical cores. Ergo, this cannot be assumed to be  managed smartly by the OS.

Comment: The distinction between logical and physical is getting pretty hazy these days. What if this code runs inside a VM where they're all logical and there are no physical cores, or the "physical" cores presented to the OS are actually logical?

Comment: @tadman: Maybe. But I'm not asking for a solution to all the set of related problems. Mine is pretty contained. I have an i7 with 4 (as of now) physical core and 4 logical ones. I also have a function that is memory bound which I cannot divide (it's an LP routine). I can run 4 instances of this function in parallel but not 8. See if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that doesn't involve changing the source code of a python module. It uses the approach suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/797534/383380). One can check that only 
the physical cores are active after running that script by doing:

```
lscpu
```

in the bash returns:

```
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,2,4,6
Off-line CPU(s) list:  1,3,5,7
Thread(s) per core:    1
```

[One can run the script linked above from within [python](https://askubuntu.com/a/155827/2413)]. In any case, after running the script above, typing these commands in python:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

returns 4.

Answer (score 87):

I know the topic is quite old now, but as it still appears as the first answer when typing 'multiprocessing logical core' in google... I feel like I have to give an additional answer because I can see that it would be possible for people in 2018 (or even later..) to get easily confused here (some answers are indeed a little bit confusing)

I can see no better place than here to warn readers about some of the answers above, so sorry for bringing the topic back to life.

**--> TO COUNT THE CPUs (LOGICAL/PHYSICAL) USE THE PSUTIL MODULE**

For a 4 physical core / 8 thread i7 for ex it will return

```
import psutil 
psutil.cpu_count(logical = False)
```

> 4

```
psutil.cpu_count(logical = True)
```

> 8

As simple as that.

There you won't have to worry about the OS, the platform, the hardware itself or whatever. **I am convinced it is much better than multiprocessing.cpu_count()** which can sometimes give weird results, from my own experience at least.

**--> TO USE N PHYSICAL CORES (up to your choice) USE THE MULTIPROCESSING MODULE DESCRIBED BY YUGI**

Just count how many physical processes you have, launch a multiprocessing.Pool of 4 workers.

Or you can also try to use the joblib.Parallel() function

joblib in 2018 is not part of the standard distribution of python, but is just a wrapper of the multiprocessing module as described by Yugi.

**--> MOST OF THE TIME, DON'T USE MORE CORES THAN AVAILABLE (unless you have benchmarked a very specific code and proved it was worth it)**

Misinformation abounds that "the OS will handle things if you specify more cores than are available". **It is absolutely 100% false**. If you use more cores than available, you will face huge performance drops. The exception would be if the worker processes are IO bound. Because the OS scheduler will try its best to work on every task with the same attention, switching regularly from one to another, and depending on the OS, it can spend up to 100% of its working time to just switching between processes, which would be disastrous.

Don't just trust me: try it, benchmark it, you will see how clear it is.

**IS IT POSSIBLE TO DECIDE WHETHER THE CODE WILL BE EXECUTED ON LOGICAL OR PHYSICAL CORE?**

If you are asking this question, this means you don't understand the way physical and logical cores are designed, so maybe you should check a little bit more about a processor's architecture.

If you want to run on core 3 rather than core 1 for example, Well I guess there are indeed some solutions, but available only if you know how to code an OS's kernel and scheduler, which I think is not the case if you're asking this question.

If you launch 4 CPU-intensive processes on a 4 physical / 8 logical processor, the scheduler will attribute each of your processes to 1 distinct physical core (and 4 logical core will remain not/poorly used). But on a 4 logical / 8 thread proc, if the processing units are (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (4,5) (5,6) (6,7), then it makes no difference if the process is executed on 0 or 1 : it is the same processing unit.

From my knowledge at least (but an expert could confirm, maybe it differs from very specific hardware specifications also) I think there is no or very little difference between executing a code on 0 or 1. In the processing unit (0,1), I am not sure that 0 is the logical whereas 1 is the physical, or vice-versa. From my understanding (which can be wrong), both are processors from the same processing unit, and they just share their cache memory / access to the hardware (RAM included), and 0 is not more a physical unit than 1.

More than that you should let the OS decide. Because the OS scheduler can take advantage of a hardware logical-core turbo boost that exist on some platforms (ex i7, i5, i3...), something else that you have no power over, and that could be truly helpful to you.

If you launch 5 CPU-intensive tasks on a 4 physical / 8 logical core, the behaviour will be chaotic, almost unpredictable, mostly dependent on your hardware and OS. The scheduler will try its best. Almost every time, you will face really bad performance.

Let's presume for a moment that we are still talking about a 4(8) classical architecture: Because the scheduler tries its best (and therefore often switches the attributions), depending on the process you are executing, it could be even worse to launch on 5 logical cores than on 8 logical cores (where at least he knows everything will be used at 100% anyway, so lost for lost he won't try much to avoid it, won't switch too often, and therefore won't lose too much time by switching).

It is 99% sure however (but benchmark it on your hardware to be sure) that almost any multiprocessing program will run slower if you use more physical core than available.

A lot of things can intervene... The program, the hardware, the state of the OS, the scheduler it uses, the fruit you ate this morning, your sister's name... In case you doubt about something, just benchmark it, there is no other easy way to see whether you are losing performances or not. Sometimes informatics can be really weird.

**--> MOST OF THE TIME, ADDITIONAL LOGICAL CORES ARE INDEED USELESS IN PYTHON (but not always)**

There are 2 main ways of doing really parallel tasks in python.

- multiprocessing (cannot take advantage of logical cores)
- multithreading (can take advantage of logical cores)

For example to run 4 tasks in parallel

--> multiprocessing will create 4 different python interpreter. For each of them you have to start a python interpreter, define the rights of reading/writing, define the environment, allocate a lot of memory, etc. Let's say it as it is: You will start a whole new program instance from 0. It can take a huge amount of time, so you have to be sure that this new program will work long enough so that it is worth it.

If your program has enough work (let's say, a few seconds of work at least), then because the OS allocates CPU-consuming processes on different physical cores, it works, and you can gain a lot of performances, which is great. And because the OS almost always allows processes to communicate between them (although it is slow) they can even exchange (a little bit of) data.

--> multithreading is different. Within your python interpreter, it will just create a small amount of memory that many CPU will be available to share, and work on it at the same time. It is WAY much quicker to spawn (where spawning a new process on an old computer can take many seconds sometimes, spawning a thread is done within a ridiculously small fraction of time). You don't create new processes, but "threads" which are much lighter.

Threads can share memory between threads very quickly, because they literally work together on the same memory (while it has to be copied/exchanged when working with different processes).

**BUT: WHY CANNOT WE USE MULTITHREADING IN MOST SITUATIONS ? IT LOOKS VERY CONVENIENT ?**

There is a very BIG limitation in python: Only one python line can be executed at a time in a python interpreter, which is called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). So most of the time, you will even LOSE performances by using multithreading, because different threads will have to wait to access to the same resource. For pure computational processing (with no IO), multithreading is USELESS and even WORSE if your code is pure python. However, if your threads involve any waiting for IO, multithreading can be very beneficial.

**--> WHY SHOULDN'T I USE LOGICAL CORES WHEN USING MULTIPROCESSING ?**

Logical cores don't have their own memory access. They can only work on the memory access and on the cache of its hosting physical processor. For example it is very likely (and often used indeed) that the logical and the physical core of a same processing unit both use the same C/C++ function on different emplacements of the cache memory at the same time. Making the treatment hugely faster indeed.

But... these are C/C++ functions ! Python is a big C/C++ wrapper, that needs much more memory and CPU than its equivalent C++ code. It is very likely in 2018 that, whatever you want to do, 2 big python processes will need much, much more memory and cache reading/writing than what a single physical+logical unit can afford, and much more that what the equivalent C/C++ truly-multithreaded code would consume. This once again, would almost always cause performances to drop. Remember that every variable that is not available in the processor's cache, will take x1000 time to read in the memory. If your cache is already completely full for 1 single python process, guess what will happened if you force 2 processes to use it: They will use it one at the time, and switch permanently, causing data to be stupidly flushed and re-read every time it switches. When the data is being read or written from memory, you might think that your CPU "is" working but it's not. It's waiting for the data ! By doing nothing.

**--> HOW CAN YOU TAKE ADVANTAGE OF LOGICAL CORES THEN ?**

Like I said there is no true multithreading (so no true usage of logical cores) in default python, because of the global interpreter lock. You can force the GIL to be removed during some parts of the program, but I think it would be a wise advise that you don't touch to it if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Removing the GIL definitely has been a subject of a lot of research (see the experimental PyPy or Cython projects that both try to do so).

For now, no real solution exists for it, as it is a much more complex problem than it seems.

There is, I admit, another solution that can work:

- Code your function in C
- Wrap it in python with ctype
- Use the python multithreading module to call your wrapped C function

This will work 100%, and you will be able to use all the logical cores, in python, with multithreading, and for real. The GIL won't bother you, because you won't be executing true python functions, but C functions instead.

For example, some libraries like Numpy can work on all available threads, because they are coded in C. But if you come to this point, I always thought it could be wise to think about doing your program in C/C++ directly because it is a consideration very far from the original pythonic spirit.

**--> DON'T ALWAYS USE ALL AVAILABLE PHYSICAL CORES **

I often see people be like "Ok I have 8 physical core, so I will take 8 core for my job". It often works, but sometimes turns out to be a poor idea, especially if your job needs a lot of I/O.

Try with N-1 cores (once again, especially for highly I/O-demanding tasks), and you will see that 100% of time, on per-task/average, single tasks will always run faster on N-1 core. Indeed, your computer makes a lot of different things: USB, mouse, keyboard, network, Hard drive, etc... Even on a working station, periodical tasks are performed anytime in the background that you have no idea about. If you don't let 1 physical core to manage those tasks, your calculation will be regularly interrupted (flushed out from the memory / replaced back in memory) which can also lead to performance issues.

You might think "Well, background tasks will use only 5% of CPU-time so there is 95% left". But it's not the case.

The processor handles one task at a time. And every time it switches, a considerably high amount of time is wasted to place everything back at its place in the memory cache/registries. Then, if for some weird reason the OS scheduler does this switching too often (something you have no control on), all of this computing time is lost forever and there's nothing you can do about it.

If (and it sometimes happen) for some unknown reason this scheduler problem impacts the performances of not 1 but 30 tasks, it can result in really intriguing situations where working on 29/30 physical core can be significantly faster than on 30/30

**MORE CPU IS NOT ALWAYS THE BEST**

It is very frequent, when you use a multiprocessing.Pool, to use a multiprocessing.Queue or manager queue, shared between processes, to allow some basic communication between them. Sometimes (I must have said 100 times but I repeat it), in an hardware-dependent manner, it can occur (but you should benchmark it for your specific application, your code implementation and your hardware) that using more CPU might create a bottleneck when you make processes communicate / synchronize. In those specific cases, it could be interesting to run on a lower CPU number, or even try to deport the synchronization task on a faster processor (here I'm talking about scientific intensive calculation ran on a cluster of course). As multiprocessing is often meant to be used on clusters, you have to notice that clusters often are underclocked in frequency for energy-saving purposes. Because of that, single-core performances can be **really** bad (balanced by a way-much higher number of CPUs), making the problem even worse when you scale your code from your local computer (few cores, high single-core performance) to a cluster (lot of cores, lower single-core performance), because your code bottleneck according to the single_core_perf/nb_cpu ratio, making it sometimes really annoying

Everyone has the temptation to use as many CPU as possible. But benchmark for those cases is mandatory.

The typical case (in data science for ex) is to have N processes running in parallel and you want to summarize the results in one file. Because you cannot wait the job to be done, you do it through a specific writer process. The writer will write in the outputfile everything that is pushed in his multiprocessing.Queue (single-core and hard-drive limited process). The N processes fill the multiprocessing.Queue.

It is easy then to imagine that if you have 31 CPU writing informations to one really slow CPU, then your performances will drop (and possibly something will crash if you overcome the system's capability to handle temporary data)

**--> Take home message**

- Use psutil to count logical/physical processors, rather than multiprocessing.cpu_count() or whatsoever
- Multiprocessing can only work on physical core (or at least benchmark it to prove it is not true in your case)
- Multithreading will work on logical core BUT you will have to code and wrap your functions in C, or remove the global lock interpreter (and every time you do so, one kitten atrociously dies somewhere in the world)
- If you are trying to run multithreading on pure python code, you will have huge performance drops, so you should 99% of the time use multiprocessing instead
- Unless your processes/threads are having long pauses that you can exploit, never use more core than available, and benchmark properly if you want to try
- If your task is I/O intensive, you should let 1 physical core to handle the I/O, and if you have enough physical core, it will be worth it. For multiprocessing implementations it needs to use N-1 physical core. For a classical 2-way multithreading, it means to use N-2 logical core.
- If you have need for more performances, try PyPy (not production ready) or Cython, or even to code it in C

Last but not least, and the most important of all: If you are really seeking for performance, you should absolutely, always, always benchmark, and not guess anything. Benchmark often reveal strange platform/hardware/driver very specific behaviour that you would have no idea about.

Comment: "Multithreading is always USELESS and even WORSE if your code is pure python" - NO.NO.NO. If your code has lots of IO, web scraper for example, individual threads will release GIL while waiting for OS to return (socket/file) data...I've seen almost linear performance improvement with thread-based parallelism in this scenario (my project was a pure python torrent client)

Answer (score 17):

**Note**: This approach doesn't work on windows and it is tested only on linux.

**Using `multiprocessing.Process`**:

Assigning a physical core to each process is quite easy when using `Process()`. You can create a for loop that iterates trough each core and assigns the new process to the new core using `taskset -p [mask] [pid]` :

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def foo():
    return

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    for process_idx in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
        os.system("taskset -p -c %d %d" % (process_idx % multiprocessing.cpu_count(), os.getpid()))
        p.start()
```

I have 32 cores on my workstation so I'll put partial results here:

```
pid 520811's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 520811's new affinity list: 0
pid 520811's current affinity list: 0
pid 520811's new affinity list: 1
pid 520811's current affinity list: 1
pid 520811's new affinity list: 2
pid 520811's current affinity list: 2
pid 520811's new affinity list: 3
pid 520811's current affinity list: 3
pid 520811's new affinity list: 4
pid 520811's current affinity list: 4
pid 520811's new affinity list: 5
...
```

As you see, the previous and new affinity of each process here. The first one is for all cores (0-31) and is then assigned to core 0, second process is by default assigned to core0 and then its affinity is changed to the next core (1), and so forth.

**Using `multiprocessing.Pool`**:

**Warning**: This approach needs tweaking the `pool.py` module since there is no way that I know of that you can extract the pid from the `Pool()`. Also this changes have been tested on `python 2.7` and `multiprocessing.__version__ = '0.70a1'`.

In `Pool.py`, find the line where the `_task_handler_start()` method is being called. In the next line, you can assign the process in the pool to each "physical" core using (I put the `import os` here so that the reader doesn't forget to import it):

```
import os
for worker in range(len(self._pool)):
    p = self._pool[worker]
    os.system("taskset -p -c %d %d" % (worker % cpu_count(), p.pid))
```

and you're done. Test:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(i):
    return

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool.map(foo,'iterable here')
```

result:

```
pid 524730's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524730's new affinity list: 0
pid 524731's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524731's new affinity list: 1
pid 524732's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524732's new affinity list: 2
pid 524733's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524733's new affinity list: 3
pid 524734's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524734's new affinity list: 4
pid 524735's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 524735's new affinity list: 5
...
```

Note that this modification to `pool.py` assign the jobs to the cores round-robinly. So if you assign more jobs than the cpu-cores, you will end up having multiple of them on the same core.

**EDIT:**

What OP is looking for is to have a `pool()` that is capable of staring the pool on specific cores. For this more tweaks on `multiprocessing` are needed (undo the above-mentioned changes first).

**Warning:**

Don't try to copy-paste the function definitions and function calls. Only copy paste the part that is supposed to be added after `self._worker_handler.start()` (you'll see it below). Note that my `multiprocessing.__version__` tells me the version is `'0.70a1'`, but it doesn't matter as long as you just add what you need to add:

**`multiprocessing`'s `pool.py`:**

add a `cores_idx = None` argument to `__init__()` definition. In my version it looks like this after adding it:

```
def __init__(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(),
             maxtasksperchild=None,cores_idx=None)
```

also you should add the following code after `self._worker_handler.start()`:

```
if not cores_idx is None:
    import os
    for worker in range(len(self._pool)):
        p = self._pool[worker]
        os.system("taskset -p -c %d %d" % (cores_idx[worker % (len(cores_idx))], p.pid))
```

**`multiprocessing`'s `__init__.py`**:

Add a `cores_idx=None` argument to definition of the `Pool()` in as well as the other `Pool()` function call in the the return part. In my version it looks like:

```
def Pool(processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(), maxtasksperchild=None,cores_idx=None):
    '''
    Returns a process pool object
    '''
    from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,cores_idx)
```

And you're done. The following example runs a pool of 5 workers on cores 0 and 2 only:

```
import multiprocessing


def foo(i):
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5,cores_idx=[0,2])
    pool.map(foo,'iterable here')
```

result:

```
pid 705235's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 705235's new affinity list: 0
pid 705236's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 705236's new affinity list: 2
pid 705237's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 705237's new affinity list: 0
pid 705238's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 705238's new affinity list: 2
pid 705239's current affinity list: 0-31
pid 705239's new affinity list: 0
```

Of course you can still have the usual functionality of the `multiprocessing.Poll()` as well by removing the `cores_idx` argument.

Comment: @user189035 Did you face any specific problem for implementing that? Because this seems to be quite alright to implement using `multiprocessing.Process` part of my answer. unless I'm missing something

Comment: @user189035 Maybe I'm missing something because now that I think, it might need a combination of both. But let me know if you got into trouble and I'll work on it

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. I also have difficulties working through your answer. Could you please append your answer to show how one can see whether an instance of foo is indeed running on a physical core as opposed to a logical one?

Comment: @user189035 check the answer. I added what you wanted. also please accept the answer if it's what you want so that other people that might be looking for the same thing understand that it worked for you in the first look.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks I think I understand now: the context argument in the Pool function determines the physical cores on which the worker is run?

Comment: @user189035 the `cores_idx` argument is a list in which you can assign the CPU cores. Don't assign higher index than your cpu cores or it will raise exceptions (I should've put `asserts`).  For instance `cores_idx=[0]` uses only core 0 and  `cores_idx=[0,1,2,3]` uses the first 4 cores. if you don't put the  `cores_idx` , any/all of them might be used as usual.

Comment: What version of python are you assuming? In version 3.4 and above there is an additional `context` argument to [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool). Do I need to adapt your code for this? Right now (python 3.4.1) I get an error when I copy paste the code (with the definition of Pool): `TypeError: Pool() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cores_idx'`

Comment: @user189035 using `multiprocessing.__version__` mine's `0.70a1`. Doesn't matter. Just add the `cores_idx` as I have mentioned.

Comment: @user189035 check the new answer and do as I wrote. don't copy paste anything except for the part that is mentioned. For the other parts, change them, but don't copy-paste them

Comment: @user189035 `TypeError: Pool() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cores_idx'` this means that you haven't edited the `__init__.py`. Please follow the instructions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126827/discussion-between-user189035-and-yugi).